# Build local repo for ubuntu 16.04 and above

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, repository, apt-mirror

I want to build a local repo for Ubuntu 16.04 with apt-mirror tool.
Can I configure it on Ubuntu 18 or do I need the same version of Ubuntu?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It does not have to be the same version. I have an 18.04 local mirror running on a 16.04 server.

Comment: So its mean that the repo for 16 its the same for 18? eventually I want to build a repo for ubuntu 16.04 version and 18.04

Comment: No, they are not the same. When you set up your `mirror.list` you specify the repos you want to pull from, bionic or xenial or whatever and where to store the data.  If you want to do more than one version, I imagine you'll have to set up two different mirror.list s and specify different directories to store the files in.  I have not tried this though.

Comment: Now its make sense to me, I opened this file in both versions and see the same urls and I didn't understand what is the difference. Thanks